# Why does Samba sometimes take a while to start working?

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, samba, sheevaplug

I was trying to get Samba to start sharing a directory. I couldn't seem to get it working, got frustrated, and gave up.  Then I checked back later, and it had started working with the configuration I gave it.

Why does it sometimes take quite a while for Samba to start sharing things, and is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: I don't think your issue was Samba. I think your issue was the machine you were trying to access Same from. Windows caches some SMB parameters, so if you make changes, Windows may be confused for a minute or so until it retries and refreshes the cached incorrect data.

Comment: Have no answer but I have experienced the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things that can be the cause of this.

It sometimes takes a while for machines to find each other with NetBIOS if that is what you're using. This is usually the case if you don't have a domain controller.

See also http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/NetworkBrowsing.html

Setting up your samba server as a WINS server, and having your windows machines use that might be a way to fix this.